# How is Cholesky decomposition used in ridge regression?

Tags: scikit-learn, ridge-regression, cholesky-decomposition

As far as I learnt, Cholesky decomposition can be used only for symmetrical positive definite matrices, but I can see it is used as solver in Sklearn-Ridge package, can somebody explain how it is used where X is clearly a non symmetric matrix like the one randomly generated in the below example...

```py
m = 20
X = 3 * np.random.rand(m, 1)
y = 1 + 0.5 * X + np.random.randn(m, 1) / 1.5

from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge
ridge_reg = Ridge(alpha=1, solver="cholesky")
ridge_reg.fit(X, y)
```

Comment: What is your source that it can be used only for symmetrical matrices?

Comment: Here it is... 
Pg no - 114
https://mml-book.github.io/book/mml-book.pdf